# How do i access a property on the objects in an array and compare it?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, properties

So, I have a array with multiple objects with multiple properties:

```
let myArr = [{
id: 1,
x: 120,
y: 150,
}, {
id: 2,
x: 170,
y: 420,
}, {
id: 3,
x: 160,
y: 220,
}, {
id: 4,
x: 140,
y: 170,
}];
```

Now I want to see if the property of one of the objects in my array matches a variable.
But I dont know how to do that!
I want to check if the value of property "id" in one of my objects matches my variable.
Something like this:

```
if(myArr[0].id == myVar){
//do something
}
```

but this for each object in my array

Comment: You'll need a loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this

```js
let myArr = [{
id: 1,
x: 120,
y: 150,
}, {
id: 2,
x: 170,
y: 420,
}, {
id: 3,
x: 160,
y: 220,
}, {
id: 4,
x: 140,
y: 170,
}];

let myVar = 1;

const found = myArr.find(element => element.id === myVar);

console.log(found)
```